# How to Inject a .ko Driver into a Linux ISO?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, software-installation, drivers, system-installation

I'm currently working on a project where I need to inject a .ko (kernel object) driver into a Linux ISO (CentOS). I've been trying to find a way to do this, but I haven't been successful so far.

Here's what I've tried:

I attempted to mount the ISO, copy its contents to a new directory, add the .ko file, and then create a new ISO from this directory. However, the driver doesn't seem to be recognized when I boot from the new ISO.

Could anyone provide a step-by-step guide on how to properly inject a .ko driver into a Linux ISO? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you mean with "injecting a .ko driver into an ISO"? The way you use the abbreviation ISO (which stands for International Standards Organization), I think you mean an ISO 9660 image file. But that's just essentially a storage format for a specific file system, as you'd find it on CD-ROMs. A) Do you want that driver to be loaded when a machine is booted using that CD-ROM? Or B) do you just mean saving that file onto an existing image file so you can later get it from there? Or C) do you want some mechanism that automatically loads a kernel driver when a CD-ROM is inserted? A, B, or C?

Comment: (or something else alltogether?)

Answer (score 0):

Section 1.7 from the [Red Hat Customer Portal](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/kernel_administration_guide/chap-documentation-kernel_administration_guide-working_with_kernel_modules) tells you how to do it on a live RHEL, so I think you have to do those steps to the ISO.

> Select a kernel module you want to load during the boot process.
>
> The modules are located in the /lib/modules/$(uname
> -r)/kernel// directory.

So your `.ko` file has to be there.

> Create a configuration file for the module:
>
> `# echo <MODULE_NAME> > /etc/modules-load.d/<MODULE_NAME>.conf`

then you have to make a `.conf` file for it.  I'm not sure how to do that but some additional searching likely will tell you what to do.

One other thing: the `.ko` module must match the kernel version, otherwise it will not load.  Most non-proprietary Linux modules are available from the same place the kernel is (kernel.org) and are built with the kernel when used and provided when the kernel is updated, so this isn't usually an issue except with proprietary stuff not in the kernel that you can't rebuild on an update.

If you have the `.ko` module on the .ISO, you can still load it manually with `insmod`, and you can use an `@reboot` line in a `crontab` to load it on boot if it doesn't need to be loaded during early boot.